# How to pass down the new operator in a method

Tags: java, class, methods

For example, if I wanted to do something like this to call a method:

```
myLights.addLight(new Fluorescent(lumens));
```

in order to create a new object in the Fluorescent class and pass down the lumens data. How would I then set up the method to receive this?

Comment: do it like you'd pass any argument to a function'

Comment: What do you want to receive

Comment: Javascript != java

Comment: Do I receive it as a string? I want to receive it so the method can create a new object in the Fluorescent class.

Comment: To be clear, Gracie, is your question about JavaScript or Java? They're very different, but this question could be either.

Comment: You're passing a `Fluorescent` object, so you receive it as a `Fluorescent` object. Can't understand for a moment where the idea of `String` came from.

Comment: What is the type of the expression `new Fluorescent(lumens)`, @Mark? That's the type of method argument you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your Lights class create a method that accepts a Fluorescent object as an argument.

```
public void addLight(Fluorescent fluorescent){
    // do something
}
```

Here is a basic example:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Light light = new Light();
    light.addLight(new Fluorescent("300 lm"));
    System.out.print(light.getLumen());
  }
}

public class Light {
  private String lumen;

  public Light() {
  }

  public void setLumens(String lumen){
    this.lumen = lumen;
  }

  public String getLumen(){
    return this.lumen;
  }

  public void addLight(Fluorescent fluorescent) {
    if(fluorescent.getLumen() != null) {
      this.lumen = fluorescent.getLumen();
    }
  }
}

public class Fluorescent {
  private String lumen;

  public Fluorescent(String lumen){
    this.lumen = lumen;
  }

  public void setLumen(String lumen){
    this.lumen = lumen;
  }

  public String getLumen(){
    return this.lumen;
  }
}
```

Seeing that a Fluorescent is a Light, you might want to look in to inheritance.
Look here for some explanation
[Java 101: Inheritance in Java, Part 1](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2987426/core-java/java-101-inheritance-in-java-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming method is not returning anything.

```
void addlight(Fluorescent a){
// your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fluorescent() {
    public Fluorescent(String lumens) {
        // do something
    }
}


public class Lights() {
    public void addLight(Fluorescent fluorescent) {
        // do something
    }
}
```